# Edit accepted answer because the newest version supports a feature

Tags: discussion

I was looking into a mongodb question and quickly found:
[How to Update Multiple Array Elements in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb)

I was disappointed to see that the accepted answer was "no, it isn't possible". In mongo 3.6 however it is possible. A colleague of mine told me so, so I turned back to the question, to happily submit a new answer...
Only somebody already did that with a great answer with already 7 upvotes.

Should I suggest an edit to the accepted answer telling people like me, that for the newest version of mongo it is possible to do now?
What I wanted to do is link to that second answer.

I already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb/47721892#comment82404524_4669702)  on the question and the accepted answer, but I'm afraid not everybody will see this...

Comment: All you can do is upvote the good answer and downvote the bad answer. Over time the better answer will rise to the top. Readers will scroll hopefully scroll past the first answer.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if it were my answer that was accepted, I would update it... Anyway, maybe the comments I left will be helpful...

Comment: Don't forget not everyone can update to a newer version of software but it might be worth adding an edit that states the answer applies to 3.6 and below and the working one applies to 3.7 and above

Comment: Just reminder: the fact the answer is "accepted" means almost nothing and definitely in no way relates to quality of the answer. "Accepted" means it was for whatever reason most useful to question's author. I.e. "I accepted this answer because it was posted by a 'friend' of mine" is not impossible scenario. You should make sure to read through other answers especially if there are significantly newer/more upvoted once.

Comment: i have the same question [i've seen someone do this on an 10 year old "Accepted" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13764884/revisions) then commented on my 4 year old comment to check the accepted answer, i don't think that very fair.